# Remove the last child in DomXPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Current structure looks like

```
<div class="...">
    //more html
    <div class="message-right">
       <div class="item1"> //more html </div>
       <div class="item2"> //more html </div>
       <div class="item3"> //more html </div>
    </div>
    //more html
</div>
```

I want to be able to get the html content inside the class 'message-right', and remove the last child. (In this case 'item3')

I should be left with the html from 'item1' and 'item2'

So far I have

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname = "message-right";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

//this is where I am stuck, need to remove the last child, 'item3'    

//this returns the html from 'message-right'
$html = $nodes->item(0)->c14n()
```

Comment: I'm guessing the tag in line 7 should be a closing one?

Comment: correct, just changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the last child element (XPath will make that easier) and delete it.

```php
$delete = $finder->query("./*[last()]", $nodes->item(0))->item(0);
$delete->parentNode->removeChild($delete);
```

Depending on what you really need you might want to fetch (and subsequently delete) that element directly using

```
//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]/*[last()]
```